# CSS/HTML Drop Menu hiding some list entries

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a HTML/CSS drop down menu and now whenever I hover my mouse over the top of the menu not every entry is showing in the drop menu. The top one or two entries are always missing. Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <ul id="navi">
        <li><a href="">Engines</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">DiniJS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Foxen2D</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Vivon3D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Team</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Rob Myers</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nate Mast</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
#navi ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#navi li {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Courier New";
}

#navi li:hover {
    background-color:#303030;
}

#navi li ul li {
    float:none;
    width:116px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:4px;
    border-top:1px solid #303030;
    display:none;
    font-size:85%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}

#navi li:hover ul li {
    display:block;
}

#navi a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}
```

I am open to any Javascript or JQuery suggestions if that is a better way to go about fixing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that all of the submenu items are stacking one on top of another. Simply moving `position: absolute;` from the `#navi li ul li` block to a new `#navi li ul` block should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When using nested list items. use class names to target. for your menu use class="sub"
for submenu (ul) and set display none and absolute for the sub ul and not for the li.

Comment: take a look at this fiddle. i have changed the first menu http://jsfiddle.net/5MaLW/5/